# How to add my loca lstorage data to amp Analytics?

Tags: javascript

let data="sn"
I need to send this data Inside Amp analytics from client side
using javascript

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt to solve your problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.